# Material-UI React using in static HTML

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react especially when using with HTML but i want to use in my web page which is HTML.I know that there is way to implant because i saw react documentation [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#add-react-in-one-minute).
First i should add

```
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```

But i dont know how to continue with adding this [library](https://material-ui.com/).
It is MATERIAL-UI React.
If anyone knows how to implant it in static HTML wab page, i will be very glad.
Sorry for bad English.

Comment: try read the CDN part here: https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/

Answer (score 1):

You can add the cdn via a **script** tag like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also take a look at the example [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/examples/cdn/index.html).

But quoting the [docs](https://material-ui.com/getting-started/installation/), this is heavily discouraged:

> ⚠️ Using this approach in production is discouraged though - the client has to download the entire library, regardless of which components are actually used, affecting performance and bandwidth utilization.

Comment: I saw this but can you give more details: for example how to implant checkbox using lib

Comment: Do you have a root element in your code where the React should be rendered? Can you share your HTML code?

Comment: I dont know really how to start.For example how to render checkbox and use it in my html web page